# If $a,b,c\ge-1$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=1$ prove
$a+b+c+a^2+b^2+c^2\le4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

> If $a,b,c\ge-1$ and $a^3+b^3+c^3=1$ prove
>   $$a+b+c+a^2+b^2+c^2\le4$$

Found this in an Olympiad Mock Paper. How do I proceed this? Any help would be much appreciated! I know of the inequalities like AM–GM, Cauchy–Schwarz and Chebyshev's!

Comment: Still, it would be nice if you stated the inequalities you know of (Cauchy/Schwarz, AM-GM, etc.)

Answer (score 5):

Let me try. You have: $$(a-1)^2 \geq 0$$ or $a^2 - a + 1 \geq a$, then using the fact that $a\geq -1$, we have $$(a+1)(a^2-a+1) \geq a(a+1)$$, then $$a^3+1 \geq a^2 + a.$$

Similarly, we have $$b^3+1 \geq b^2+b.$$
$$c^3+1 \geq c^2+c.$$

Summing up, we have $$(a^3+b^3+c^3) + 3 \geq a+b+c+a^2+b^2+c^2.$$

Now, you get the conclusion.

Comment: Inequalities whose LHS are of the form $f(a)+f(b)+f(c)$ give a strong hint of "separation of variables" and prove the separated inequalities of a single variable.

Comment: Thanks for the beautiful solution. Well,id like to know how did you decide to start with (a-1)^2 >= 0? i always tried using (a+1)^2.

Comment: @SajidRizvi You can have a guess at this from when the inequality is saturated. A little inspection shows it is saturated when $(a,b,c)$ is a permutation of $(-1,1,1)$. This suggests that $1$ is in some sense the "stationary point" of this constrained maximization problem, while $-1$ is simply the restriction imposed by the boundary condition. Since the whole thing is at most cubic, you could have good luck starting by multiplying the boundary condition $a+1\ge0$ and the stationary condition $(a-1)^2\ge0$ together.

Comment: Well. I start to study  $(a+1)^3$ and $4(a^3+1)$ and as you can see easily, $(a+1)^3 \leq 4(a^3+1)$. And I realize that I can make it more simply by just compare $a^3+1$ and $a+a^2$.